# Referencing return function?

Tags: php, function, return, dreamweaver

I'm returning a simple function with two variables,

```
function checkerValidate(){
$emptyOrNot = "";
$validOrNot = "";

    if(!empty($_POST['domain']))
    {//not empty
        $emptyOrNot = "notEmptyUrl";            
        if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === TRUE) {
            $validOrNot = "validUrl";
        }else{
            $validOrNot = "notValidUrl";
        }
    }else
    {//empty
        $emptyOrNot = "emptyUrl";
    }
    return array($emptyOrNot, $validOrNot);

}
```

To reference the two variables outside the function I use:

```
<?php echo checkerValidate()[0]; ?> 
<?php echo checkerValidate()[1]; ?>
```

I tried and upload to the server and it was working, however the I'm using Dreamweaver IDE and it states that checkerValidate()[0] and checkerValidate()[1] are not valid.

Can anyone clarify on this?

Comment: Why would you do that? Valid expression or not... you're calling and executing the whole function each time you want to use any of the values! Wouldn't it be simpler to assign the return value to a variable and then use it as a regular array? Unless you actually need to re-execute it each time, of course.

Comment: @AJPerez thanks, will use your way just to be safe

Answer (score 1):

That syntax is valid from [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-102). There is a possibility that your IDE is set to syntax check a lower version of PHP which is why it thinks it is wrong.

Your server obviously has a version of PHP greater than or equal to 5.4 so it works just fine (you can check using `php -v`).